# barSeries can not contains multiple fields in yField via Javascript?

Tags: javascript-remoting, charts, visualforce-charting, remote-action

I can render this barSeries from controller

[image]

```
page:
    <apex:chart id="barChart" height="400" width="100%" data="{!dataArray}">
        <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" />
        <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="{!strAreas}" grid="true" />
        <apex:barSeries stacked="true" axis="left" 
              xField="name" yField="{!strAreas}" />
    </apex:chart>

controller:
    strAreas = 'data1,data2,data3,data4,data5';
```

But recently I try to change datasource to Javascript, it not work.

I can monitor field: data01, data02, data03 in the array from $RemoteAction.

[image]

Even I filled fixed value "data01,data02" in yField and fields, it still not work.

Is it possible to fill one more field in yField and fields from Javascript dynamically?

Comment: Give us the the complete code so that we can tell what is wrong.

Comment: Here is link that shows how to use data from JS https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_refreshing_data_javascript_remoting.htm

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I dig the method from Chrome Developer Tools.

Here is the code sample I used :

```
<apex:chart id="barChart" name="RemotingBarChart" height="400" width="100%" data="retrieveChart2Data">
    <apex:legend position="right" />
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="YearMonth" />
    <apex:axis id="Chart2ColumnsA" type="Numeric" position="left" fields="data01,data02,data03" grid="true">
        <apex:chartLabel rotate="20" />
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:barSeries id="Chart2ColumnsB" title="Columns,1,2,3,4" gutter="150" orientation="vertical" stacked="true" axis="left" xField="YearMonth" yField="data01,data02,data03">
        <apex:chartTips height="30" width="140" />
    </apex:barSeries>
</apex:chart>

<script type="text/javascript">
    retrieveChart2Data = function(callback) {
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.extCon.getretrieveChart2Data}',
            para1,
            para2,
            para4,
            function(result, event) {
                if (event.status && result) {
                    callback(result.data);
                    // Change chart yField
                    RemotingBarChart.getSeries()[0].yField = result.xFields; 
                    // Change chart title
                    RemotingBarChart.getSeries()[0].title = result.xColumns; 

                    RemotingBarChart.reload(result.data);
                } else {
                    // handling exception
                }
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

I have a chart : `RemotingBarChart`, and the chart data comes from JS function `retrieveChart2Data`.

In that function, we can use `RemotingBarChart.getSeries()` to fetch `<apex:barSeries />` object, it's a collection; So we can use this collection `RemotingBarChart.getSeries()[#].yField` to reset y Fields we want to display.

Attentions:

- We need generate chart before we reset it.
- After all steps we do, we need reload the chart.

Enjoy it.